# OpenLayers > GeoServer WFS requests EPSG:3857

Tags: sql-server-2008, openlayers, postgis, geoserver

Something is seriously wrong with the WFS implementation in Geoserver 2.5.

I loaded a dataset into SQL Server and PostGIS. The dataset consists of a few points and is in native EPSG:3857.

The Geometry_Columns table is set for the SQL Server connection and everything appears to be fine in the Geoserver setup.

However, trying to access the WFS through OpenLayers:

WFS 1.0.0 | GET | Fixed | SQL Server > **OK**

WFS 1.0.0 | GET | Fixed | PostGIS > **OK**

WFS 1.0.0 | POST | Fixed | SQL Server > **OK**

WFS 1.0.0 | POST | Fixed | PostGIS > **OK**

WFS 1.0.0 | GET | BBOX | SQL Server > **Fail**

WFS 1.0.0 | GET | BBOX | PostGIS > **OK**

WFS 1.0.0 | POST | BBOX | SQL Server > **Fail**

WFS 1.0.0 | POST | BBOX | PostGIS > **Fail**

WFS 1.1.0 | GET | Fixed | SQL Server > **OK (but not displayed on map)**

WFS 1.1.0 | GET | Fixed | PostGIS > **OK (but not displayed on map)**

WFS 1.1.0 | POST | Fixed | SQL Server > **OK**

WFS 1.1.0 | POST | Fixed | PostGIS > **OK**

WFS 1.1.0 | GET | BBOX | SQL Server > **Fail**

WFS 1.1.0 | GET | BBOX | PostGIS > **OK (but not displayed on map)**

WFS 1.1.0 | POST | BBOX | SQL Server > **Fail**

WFS 1.1.0 | POST | BBOX | PostGIS > **Fail**

The only BBOX filtered request which succeeds is 1.0.0 GET on PostGIS datasource.

The GeoServer is publicly accessible if someone would like to run the tests for themselves. Any advice is welcome. I really need to get this working with SQL Server.

http://developer.system-ns.net:8080/geoserver/MobileSurvey/ows?service=WFS&request=getcapabilities

Here is how I call the WFS from Openlayers 2.13 as a POST request:

```
var wfsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('CATASTRO', {
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({

        version: '1.0.0',
        url: 'http://developer.system-ns.net:8080/geoserver/MobileSurvey/wfs',
        srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
        featurePrefix: 'MobileSurvey',
        featureType: 'CATASTRO_SQL3857',
        geometryName: 'GEOMETRY',
        featureNS: 'http://argeomatica.com/MobileSurvey'

    })
});
```

This is the SQL Server datasource. Change the featureType to 'catastro_pg3857' for the PostGIS datasource. I switch the strategy from Fixed to BBOX, and the version between '1.0.0' and '1.1.0' for the different tests.

Here is my GET request:

```
var wfsOptions = {
    url: 'http://developer.system-ns.net:8080/geoserver/MobileSurvey/ows?',
    params: {
        request: 'GetFeature',
        service: 'WFS',
        version: '1.0.0',
        typeName: 'catastro_pg3857',
        srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
    },
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML({
        featureNS: 'http://argeomatica.com/MobileSurvey',
        geometryName: 'GEOMETRY'
    })
}
wfsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('CATASTRO', {
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    visibility: true,
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP(wfsOptions)
});
```

Cheers, 
Dennis

Comment: I just got this running with MapServer. WFS 1.0.0 / 1.1.0, GET / POST, Fixed / BBOX are all OK with MapServer using the same SQL Server data source as in my GeoServer setup. Still would like to know why this isn't working with GeoServer. I was always under the impression that GeoServer is more advanced than MapServer. Plus, I like the web GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first attempt would be to look at invalid geometries in sqlserver. Your postgis layer shows correctly.

When I generated plain KML output from your geoserver for sql server it throws, org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds for CATASTRO_SQL3857

for postgis, KML was generated without error.

Try this:

Update < Tablename here > set geom = geom.MakeValid();

Curious to know the result...

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I haven't actually set any bounds for the data which might be a possible issue. I don't think the geometries are a problem since the dataset consists of only point geometries. Another issue might be that the geometries objects are defined with SRID 0. All data is stored in the same projection and no transformation is required. But I can see that this may be an issue for the plugin client which is trying to request/consume the data from this table.

Comment: Yes it can be missing SRID too, update tablename set geom.STSrid = 3857;

Comment: That's the one. Should have thought about this before.

Comment: Strangely, I could no longer filter the table with MapServer after moving the data to my Azure database. Changing the SRID back to 0 fixed this. MapServer doesn't seem to like having an SRID in an spatial Azure SQL table. GeoServer doesn't even like to connect to Azure.

Comment: Geoserver does connect with sql azure. You need to manually install extension, if you didn't do it follow instrustions here: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html